# Pyinstaller выдает ошибку ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pyinstaller, jwt

Пишу приложение на Python, используя PyCharm и конвертируя его при помощи Pyinstaller в .exe файл. Установил библиотеку pyjwt через pip install pyjwt и использую ее через import jwt. В среде разработки все работает как надо и модуль свою функцию выполняет. Далее делаю билд приложения командой
pyinstaller main.py  --noconfirm --onefile --icon resources\logo.ico --add-data 'resources;resources',
после чего exe показывает консоль с такой ошибкой и вылетает:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jwt'
[728] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

Версия python 3.10
Версия PyJWT 2.8.0 (хотя пробовал и 1.7.1)

Пробовал устанавливать PyJWT версией ниже. Кроме того генерировал .exe используя тег --onefile и не используя (мало ли, вдруг exe некорректно собирается). Пробовал импортировать отдельную функцию через from jwt import decode. Прописывал --hidden-import "jwt" и --hidden-import "PyJWT"